# Arch Linux: problem in the installation process

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, pacman

I go through AIF (installation framework) till "Install packages". In that step, I get the error:
`error: failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)` and then follows the list of every single package that pacman has ever seen + `exists on system`. My search all over the net just centered me on pacman's package list, but I'm absolutely new to Arch gang and don't know what to do.

I'm not able to step through installation any further.

Comment: What installation media are you using?

Comment: CD. ISO burnt to CD. And its the 2011-08 version, which ought to be the last.

Comment: Did you opt for installing from the local or remote sources? In any event, you are probably best scrubbing the install and restarting...

Comment: I chose local, only the local base, because I just wanted to get it on my HDD, I could try different cases later. And I did restart the whole PC several times and tried over and over, but everything is still the same.

Comment: Delete the package cache and reinstall - or use the remote option to pull up-to-date packages.

Comment: you mean of the package cache that is live in RAM right? and how could that result in removal of "duplicates"? well, the latter I'm asking of curiosity honestly :-D

And ok, I'll do that and tell the result. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know what your problem is, but hang in there, Arch is worth it!  You could try downloading a different ISO.  They have nightly snapshots on the site.

Comment: Well, the problem was perhaps one of my most stupid mistakes that history will never forget! I had removed and re-added my volume during install, thinking that the contents are wiped, but it seems that Arch Installer doesn't do that, and the existence of an Ubuntu installation on that volume was the source of conflicts!
Anyway, Now I have Arch on my PC, but now screwed in configuring X/LXDE. I'll ask it as another question. Thank all of you for your great comments! :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution could be `rm -R *` in the destination directory, or any other method to clear the destination volume, whichever is more convenient. And then proceeding with the installation once again.